# Loop through three arrays, apply function to elements and store the outputs in a matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I want to loop through different elements of 3 arrays and create a matrix as a function of their values.

My `a` vector ranges from 1 to 5, my `b` vector ranges from 1 to 5 and my `x` vector ranges from 2 to 10 as shown below. Then for particular values from `a` and `b`, using the equation `y=a*x+b`, I want the resulting `y` vector corresponding to the `x` values stored in the 1st column vector of the `y` matrix.

After that, changing `a` and `b` one by one, I want the results of different `y` to be stored in corresponding columns of the `y` matrix . How can I proceed to achieve that?

---

Here is the code I tried:

```
function mathstrial
    a = [1:1:5];
    b = [1:1:5];
    x = [2:2:10];    
    for e1 = a
        for e2 = b
            for e3 = x
                y = e1*x+e2;
            end
        end
    end
    disp(y)
end
```

I want the result to be

```
y =
3   4   5   6   7  ..
5   6   7   8   9  ..
7   8   9   10  11 ..
9   10  11  12  13 ..
11  12  13  14  15 ..
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without any loops - the more "MATLAB-esque" way of doing things.

```
% Your a and b, to get combinations as a 5x5 grid we use meshgrid
[a,b] = meshgrid(1:5, 1:5);
% We want to make a 5x5x5 3D matrix, where the 2D layers each use a different value
% for x, and the gridded a and b we just generated. Get the layered x:
x = repmat(reshape(2:2:10, 1, 1, []), 5, 5, 1);
% Now we want the corresponding layered a and b
a = repmat(a, 1, 1, 5); b = repmat(b, 1, 1, 5);
% Now calculate the result, ensuring we use element-wise multiplication .*
y = a.*x + b; 
% Reshape to be a 2D array, collapsing the 3rd dimension
y = reshape(y(:,:).', [], 5, 1);
```

Result as you wanted:

```
y = 
[3,   4,   5,   6,   7
 5,   6,   7,   8,   9
 7,   8,   9,  10,   11
 9,   10,  11,  12,  13
 ...
 41,  42,  43,  44,  45
 51,  52,  53,  54,  55]
```

---

You could easily make this more generic by using `size` in place of the 5s to get the appropriate sizes.

Comment: Nice! And it is very clear what steps you take. This is how you avoid loops. Maybe it is worth a different topic but it always seems to me matlab does computations either fast and very memory heavy (repmat), or slow (loopy) and with minimal memory usage. Am I correct?

Comment: That is a pretty big generalisation, depends what youre trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

you can build up `y` in a single `for loop`

```
a = [1:1:5];
b = [1:1:5];
x = [2:2:10];
y = zeros(5,5,5);
for ct = 1:length(a)
    y(:,:,ct) = (a(ct).*x)'+b;
end
```

with `b` over the second and `a` over the third dimension.

Or even in a single unreadable line

```
y=repmat((a'.*x),[1,1,length(b)])+repmat(permute(b,[1,3,2]),[length(x),length(a),1])
```

with `a` over the second, and `b` over the third dimension

Comment: You can built up `y` without a single `for loop` ;)

Comment: Yes, in a single line even. :)

Answer (score -2):

```
a = [1:1:5];
b = [1:1:5];
x = [2:2:10];
y = zeros(5,5,5);
for i = 1:5
    for j = 1:5
        for k =1:5

            y(i,j,k) = i*x(k)+j

        end
    end
end
final_y = reshape(y, [5, 25])
```

Comment: the matrix y will be three-dimentional

Comment: sir how will i place the results for different k side by side in 1 matrix? suppose                                                      [ y(:,:,1)   y(:,:,2)   y(:,:,3)    y(:,:,4)    y(:,:,5)  ]

Comment: final_y = horzcat(y(:,:,1),y(:,:,2),y(:,:,3),y(:,:,4),y(:,:,5))

Comment: Sir can i make it come in a loop .. if k contains n=100 numbers

Comment: @hrk23 , i change in the main answer

Comment: than you very much sir @Jose